# Python: use .search method to extract everything between 2 words which occur more than once

Tags: python, regex, extract, attributeerror

I have a VHDL file which contains some paragraph I want to extract.
Generally, it looks like this:

```
Declaration 1.
Some codes.
(Following are paragraphs I want to extract)
case (state) is
    case body 1
end case;

Declaration 2.
Some codes.
(Following are paragraphs I want to extract)
case (state) is
    case body 2
end case;
```

So the "case body 1" and "case body 2" are what I want. "case (state) is" and "end case;" can be matched along or not, it does not matter.
I have tried some methods like:

```
f1=open('/home/liuduo/Desktop/f2.vhd')
data=f1.read()
pattern=re.compile('case (state) is[\s\S]*?end case;')
reg=pattern.search(data).group()
```

or

```
pattern=re.compile('(?<=\bcase\b).*?(?=\bend\b)')
reg=pattern.search(data).group()
```

or

```
pattern=re.compile('.*?case(.*?)end.*?')
reg=pattern.search(data).group()
```

and many other methods with the help of many examples in Stackflow (thank all!). But nothing seems to work.

The error I got is "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'" which shows nothing is matched.
 I am quite new to Python (3 days...) and have weak background in JAVA so the REexp really confused me a lot. I wonder if anyone who can help me out with this?

Thank you so much!

P.S. If this is asked before, I am really sorry about this, first question on Stackflow after hours of searching for answers. PLZ help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
pattern=re.compile(r'case \S+ is\s*(.*?)\s*end case', re.DOTALL)
matches=pattern.findall(data)

print(matches)
# ['case body 1', 'case body 2']
```

Your first regex fails because `()` are special characters in regex that need to be escaped to match them literally.

Your second and third regex fail because a `.` doesn't match newlines by default.

The `search` method only returns the first match, so I used `findall` to get a list  of all the matches.

Further explanation on request.

Comment: Hi, Mike! Thanks for your timely answer. But the problem is I will write "case body 1" and "case body 2" to another file. However as I tried before a list of strings which returned by "findall" can't be written to other files. Moreover is it ".match" only return the first match? ".search" is the same?

Comment: @LiuDuo. You can use a `for in` loop to iterate the list and write each result to file. And yes, `match` and `search` both return the first match only.

Comment: thank you very much! It works just as what I expected!! One more question: what is the meaning of 'r' before 'case \S+ is\s*(.*?)\s*end case'? I found it works as well if the 'r' is deleted, and many other codes has such a 'r' in similar places. Once again, thank you very much. Moreover, I didn't use "for in " but ".join()" to have it transformed to string! Very exciting experience!

Comment: The `r` means _raw string_, and is included so backslashes are left in the string and not treated as string escapes. It works without it because `\s` and `\S` are not string escape sequences anyway. Try `re.match(r"\bx", "x")` vs `re.match("\bx", "x")`, and only the first will match, because in the second the `\b` is treated as a string escape sequence for the backspace character before it has a chance to be treated as a regex escape sequence for a word boundary. In short, it's good practice to use raw strings for regex.